# FeinCMS, how to access attribute of a content_types parent object

Tags: django, feincms

So let's say I have a content_type RichTextContent which is registered to Page.

Can I render attributes of the Page instance in the template of the RichTextContent content_type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all content instances have `parent` attribute, this refers to `Page` instance.